# Javascript: import one and the rest?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

For object `const a = {b: 1, c: 2, d: 3}`, we can do destructuring like this: `const {b, ...rest} = a`.

I'm wondering if it's also possible for `import`s.

Say I have a file `file1.js`:

```
// file1.js
export const a = 1;
export const b = 2;
export const c = 3;
```

Can I import from this file by importing one and the rest like destructuring?

```
// file2.js
import {a, ...rest} from "file1";
```

Comment: Imports declare aliases. `rest` is not an alias for anything exported by the module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not directly, there's no `import` form for it.

What you can do instead is import the module's module namespace object, then use destructuring on it:

```
import * as file1 from "file1";
const {a, ...rest} = file1;
```

FWIW, the specification has an example list of `import` forms [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-import-forms-mapping-to-importentry-records). It doesn't show what you can and can't combine, but those are the basic forms.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into modules and the possible forms of `import` and `export` in some depth in Chapter 13 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.)